# Hacer un algoritmo para mostrar el primer digito Par?

Tags: c#, array, .net

[image: me imprime en pantalla todos los números pares cuando yo solo quiero el primero]

el algoritmo tiene que mostrar en pantalla el primer digito par de todos los introducidos sin importar su posición, pero cuando ejecuto me muestra todos los dígitos pares y yo solo necesito el primero.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el código como texto

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [algunas razones por las que debes incluir el código en texto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/182188) y no como imagen.

Comment: Despues del Console.WriteLine(par[0]); ponle una 'break;' para que salga  del loop.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que poner el comando 'break' despues de la linea 'Console.WriteLine' (linea 134), para que escape del For. Al ejecutarse y entrar al if, ya cumplio la condicion, asi que tienes que usar Break, para que no siga iterando.

Comment: Gracias. me funciono